# Indexes for triangles of dodecahedron centered at the origin

Tags: c#, 3d, polyhedra

Wikipedia says that dodecahedron at the origin has vertices with this coordinates(x,y,z):

```
   (±1, ±1, ±1)
   (0, ±1/φ, ±φ)
   (±1/φ, ±φ, 0)
   (±φ, 0, ±1/φ)

where φ is golden ratio (φ = (1 + √5) / 2 ≈ 1.618 )
```

Let's say that I'll have this vertexes in vertexBuffer - which will be an array of Point3D.
I need prepare indexes of triangles for indexBuffer(which is an array of int). Dodecahedron has 12 faces, each face is pentagon and I will create each face from 3 triangles this way: 
[image]

```
first triangle: a,e,b
second triangle: b,e,d
third triangle: d,c,b
```

For easier polyhedron I can draw it and then mark vertices and then easily get the indexes, but in this case it's not good way, cause after this Icosahedron, which has 20 faces, is waiting for me :/ 
 
**So my question is: Is there any easier way how to get indexes for this vertices according requirements specified above?**

Note:
I should also mentioned, that I couldn't use openGL or DirectX. We should practise 3D graphics without this libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The first set of 8 vertices defines a cube.

The 3x4 remaining points come in 6 pairs that lie outside each of the 6 faces of the cube.

Each set of six points (four vertices of the cube face and the corresponding two points further away from the origin) form a pattern that repeats six times. You can get 6 triangles from each set.

An icosahedron is actually simpler: it has only 20 triangles instead of 36. It has a similar pattern, which you can see on its Wikipedia page.